# WebClient.UploadFileAsync - delete after upload completion

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm using this code to upload files asynchronously to my web server.

```
WebClient fileUploader = new WebClient();
fileUploader.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(fileUploader_Completed);
fileUploader.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/upload.php"), "POST", @"C:\foo\bar.txt");
```

I want to remove the file from disk after uploading. Can I pass the local filename to the UploadFileCompletedEventHandler in some way? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anoter overload of UploadFileAsync - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144234.aspx that takes userToken argument. You'll receve that argument as AsyncCompletedEventArgs.UserState in complete handler.

Sample available at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploadfilecompletedeventhandler.aspx